# Recibir y leer contenido de SMS en Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

en resumen mi aplicación llama a una Raspberry con GPS que corta la llamada y contesta con un SMS con las coordenadas en la que se encuentra.
Con mi código consigo llamarlo, pero cuando recibo el SMS no consigo que mi APP lo detecte y lea el contenido. 
He creado este `BroadcastReceiver` desde el que pretendo que cuando llegue el mensaje guarde la información en un fichero, pero la app nunca entra en este receiver:

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private int num;
    private int UBIC=615202383;
        private String numero="0";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();



        if(bundle !=null){
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i=0; i<sms.length;i++){
                SmsMessage mensajes = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) (sms[i]));
                String numero = mensajes.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String coordenadas = mensajes.getMessageBody().toString();
                num = Integer.parseInt(numero);
                if(num == UBIC ){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Posición recibida de: "+ numero +": "+coordenadas,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Guardar en fichero cuando funcione...
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Mi Manifest es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hector.tfgapp">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo5"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />

        <service android:name=".MiIntentService" />


        <receiver android:name=".MessageReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Si hay alguna otra forma más fácil de hacerlo os agradecería la información.

Comment: Hola @wasous , comentabas que se cerraba, ya revisaste el LogCat?

Comment: No se ha vuelto a cerrar, ya me funciona bien. Solo pasó la primera vez. Gracias por preguntar. Ahora estoy intentando leer el SMS que me contesta la Raspberry Pi.